# How to uninstall Yahoo toolbar for Firefox 15

Tags: uninstall, toolbar

My kids downloaded something, which installed the Yahoo toolbar. I have tried every trick I can think of, and all I can do is get the bar to not show itself. There still is a Yahoo! menu, and I think it might be interfering with other web sites, but I'm not completely sure... Anyways, I want to get it off completely. What do I need to do?

I have tried:

1. Removing it from Add-ons (Didn't show up).
2. Removing it via the bar itself (No pencil menu showing up)
3. Removing via add/remove programs (Again, nothing showing up)
4. Massive google searching (I can't seem to find anything)

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which version/edition of Windows is it?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox?

Comment: @techie007: I've now tried uninstalling Firefox, no good. I'm running windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finally get it off, I had to go digging, and manually delete the directory. I'm running on a windows XP system, and found it at the following directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\EOLUser\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\kyado4lr.default\extensions
```

In general, one can find the directory to start searching at [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_extensions), which will give you:

```
Windows NT (NT4.x/2000/XP/Vista/7)  "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"
Windows 95 (without Desktop Update)     C:\Windows\Mozilla
Windows 95 (with Desktop Update)/98/Me  C:\Windows\Application Data\Mozilla\

C:\Windows\Profiles\<Windows login/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\
Unix/Linux  ~/.mozilla/
Mac OS X    ~/Library/Mozilla/

~/Library/Application Support/
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Yahoo toolbar is installed by other 'Free' Software.

You may want to prune your installed applications.

EXAMPLE: I found that installing Infra-record installed Yahoo! for example; something about the method of installation kept it installed and enabled until I removed Infra-record.  Incidentally, not all mirrors of the installation program installed the toolbar.  I'm not picking on Infra-record, I'm suggesting that any legitimate free application could have had its installer modified to keep the toolbar installed.

Comment: I've pruned everything on the computer that I don't recognize from the add/remove programs, nothing.

Comment: I Assume you're already downloaded malware removal software, and tried to use that to remove the issue?

Comment: I'm on my third such tool, and while I'm finding the files that likely started this, I'm not finding the files in place...